# Free Text Editor in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, text-editor

Have tried (vue-2)text editor in vue js. It's working in local, When i tried to move the same code in Prod Env, had performed the vulnerability check using below command, npm audit. The vue-2 editor is not working in local after performing the vulnerability check. Please guide me to use the free text editor in vue js which support in the all environments.

```
   Have tried the below code, which is working in local, before checking the vulnerability.  Please check it and let me know.
```

```
          <script>  
           import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";

            export default {
              name: "fp-extension-createblock",
              components: {    
              VueEditor,
            },
            data() {
              return {
                 content: ''
               };
            },
            mounted() {
            },
            methods: { }
           };
         </script>
         <template>
            <vue-editor v-model="block.content"></vue-editor>
         </template>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Switch to vue-quill-editor: If you continue to face issues with vue-2-editor, you can consider switching to a different text editor component for Vue.js. One popular alternative is vue-quill-editor, which is actively maintained and has good support.

First, install vue-quill-editor:

```
npm install vue-quill-editor
```

then,

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <quill-editor v-model="content"></quill-editor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { quillEditor } from 'vue-quill-editor';

  export default {
    components: {
      quillEditor,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        content: '',
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```